# Ostream output gives extra adress, when using nested functions

Tags: c++, stream, ostream

I have few functions with switches dealing with ostreams to specify exact template type for object to print.
BUT somehow when i'm using nested functions extra address appears in output stream.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


ostream & tmp2( ostream & in )
{
   return in << "out";
}

ostream & tmp( ostream & in )
{
   return in << tmp2( in );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int t = 2;
   switch (t)
   {
      case 2:
         std::cout << tmp;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
"out0x600e08"

any ideas why is that and how to prevent this?

Comment: You want `std::cout << tmp(cin);`.

Comment: Your code gave me [compile error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/19CciuvkFMECj4yc). What's your compiler?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, the function `tmp()` will require one argument.

Comment: What do you expect `in << tmp2( in )` to do?

Comment: @MikeCAT, compiled successfully on [ideone](http://ideone.com/3v0Ymr).

Comment: Also got [compile error](http://rextester.com/NPEKFG416949) with VC++.

Comment: @BatCoder That is a bug in G++ pre 5.3(maybe including 5.3 as well).  It does not compile with the latest version as it should: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6122e093cf377dd8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ostream & tmp( ostream & in )
{
   return in << tmp2( in );
}
```

That is equivalent to:

```
ostream & tmp( ostream & in )
{
   tmp2(in);
   in << in;   // This line causes the extra output.
   return in;
}
```

You probably meant to use:

```
ostream & tmp( ostream & in )
{
   return tmp2( in );
}
```

Comment: Yup it was this! Thanks